# Invalid View Tags 1487248

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

when we create view_tags,

```
6042082954722?view_tags=["https://da.info.co/tr?key=view_tags"]
```

We get this error :

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid parameter",
    "type": "FacebookApiException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 1487248,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "Invalid View Tags",
    "error_user_msg": "The view tags are invalid.",
    "fbtrace_id": "FxlLxqGwwC4"
  },
  "__fb_trace_id__": "FxlLxqGwwC4"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just use any tag for Facebook, only certified tags. It looks like this one is not a valid domain to be used.